# My textview just gives me bottom overflowed by pixels. I have tried putting it into expanded,singlechildscrollview but still same error is recieved?

Tags: flutter, textview

This is my code for better understanding. I am using text view to display paragraphs inside a column. The size of my container is fixed in which my text view is placed.

Edit:-

When I use singlechildscrollview on textview with scroll direction : Axis. horizontal it works but when I change the scroll direction to vertical it shows the same error.

```
    Container(
    color: Colors.amber,
    width: double.infinity,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
    child: PageView(
        //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        //to get list as pages using pageview
        children: List.generate(4, (index) {
          //creating indivadiuals pages for pageview inside a list
          map_of_answers['q $index'] = idea['q $index'];
          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                //this is our question textview widget
                width: double.infinity,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(list_of_questions[index],
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 25)),
              ),
              Container(
                //our answer textview widget
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Text(
                  idea['q $index'],
                  style: GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: 15),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
        controller: controller,
        onPageChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            activeIndex = value;
          });
        }));
```

[Here is the screenshot of the error on my phone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D3DF.jpg)

Comment: You can try to minimize the height: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65`

Comment: @Akif I tried minimizing the height, it just makes the overall page view smaller and still the text view gives the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the Column Widget with `SingleChildScrollView` this will solve the problem :

```
Container(
    color: Colors.amber,
    width: double.infinity,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
    child: PageView(
        //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        //to get list as pages using pageview
        children: List.generate(4, (index) {
          //creating indivadiuals pages for pageview inside a list
          map_of_answers['q $index'] = idea['q $index'];
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            // add this widget
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  //this is our question textview widget
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Text(list_of_questions[index],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 25)),
                ),
                Container(
                  //our answer textview widget
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Text(
                    idea['q $index'],
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),
        controller: controller,
        onPageChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            activeIndex = value;
          });
        }),
  ),
);
```

Comment: thanks buddy your solution worked for me. But when i wrap textview in singlechildscrollview why don't it works in vertical direction while working in horizontal direction.

Comment: You mean    scrollDirection in PageView or scrollDirection  in  singlechildscrollview  ?

Comment: scrollDirection in singlechildscrollview ??

Comment: yes both pageView And singlechildscrollview  have propertyscrollDirection

Comment: bro i am saying i used scrollDirection in singlechildscrollView not in pageview.

Answer (score 1):

Container adapts its size accordingly to the child widget if you don't specify its `height` and `width`. Meaning if `height` is empty, it will look at its child `height` to size itself. In this case, it's your `Text` widget. Since your `Text` widget is given unlimited height, it will display all of its current content, thus leading to overflow, or more than the `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85` height.

You can either specify the `Container` height or make it scrollable. Wrapping it with `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView` can be done either way.